# Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

I have the following log table for user messages (simplified form) in Postgres 9.2:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    log_date DATE,
    user_id  INTEGER,
    payload  INTEGER
);
```

It contains up to one record per user and per day. There will be approximately 500K records per day for 300 days. payload is ever increasing for each user (if that matters).

I want to efficiently retrieve the latest record for each user before a specific date. My query is:

```
SELECT user_id, max(log_date), max(payload) 
FROM log 
WHERE log_date <= :mydate 
GROUP BY user_id
```

which is extremely slow. I have also tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(user_id), log_date, payload
FROM log
WHERE log_date <= :mydate
ORDER BY user_id, log_date DESC;
```

which has the same plan and is equally slow.

So far I have a single index on `log(log_date)`, but doesn't help much.

And I have a `users` table with all users included. I also want to retrieve the result for some some users (those with `payload > :value`).

Is there any other index I should use to speed this up, or any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Try an index on `(user_id, aggr_date)` or an additional one on `user_id` alone. Also for any performance related questions please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: "SELECT user_id, max(log_date), max(payload) 
FROM log 
WHERE log_date <= :mydate 
GROUP BY user_id" not only slow, but also returns the wrong answer, since max(log_date) and max(payload) don't necessarily sit in one row.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

For best read performance you need a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX log_combo_idx
ON log (user_id, log_date DESC NULLS LAST);
```

To make **[index only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)** possible, add the otherwise not needed column `payload` in a [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) with the `INCLUDE` clause (Postgres 11 or later):

```
CREATE INDEX log_combo_covering_idx
ON log (user_id, log_date DESC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE (payload);
```

See:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)

Fallback for older versions:

```
CREATE INDEX log_combo_covering_idx
ON log (user_id, log_date DESC NULLS LAST, payload);
```

Why `DESC NULLS LAST`?

- [Unused index in range of dates query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90183/3684)

For ***few*** rows per `user_id` or small tables `DISTINCT ON` is typically fastest and simplest:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For ***many*** rows per `user_id` an [**index skip scan** (or **loose index scan**)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) is (much) more efficient. That's not implemented up to Postgres 15 [(work is ongoing)](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/23/1741/). But there are ways to emulate it efficiently.

[Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) require Postgres **8.4+**.
[`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) requires Postgres **9.3+**.
The following solutions go beyond what's covered in the [**Postgres Wiki**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan).

### 1. No separate table with unique users

*With a separate `users` table, solutions in **2.** below are typically simpler and faster. Skip ahead.*

#### 1a. Recursive CTE with `LATERAL` join

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (                                -- parentheses required
   SELECT user_id, log_date, payload
   FROM   log
   WHERE  log_date <= :mydate
   ORDER  BY user_id, log_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT l.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT l.user_id, l.log_date, l.payload
      FROM   log l
      WHERE  l.user_id > c.user_id  -- lateral reference
      AND    log_date <= :mydate    -- repeat condition
      ORDER  BY l.user_id, l.log_date DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) l
   )
TABLE  cte
ORDER  BY user_id;
```

This is simple to retrieve arbitrary columns and probably best in current Postgres. More explanation in chapter *2a.* below.

#### 1b. Recursive CTE with correlated subquery

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (                                           -- parentheses required
   SELECT l AS my_row                          -- whole row
   FROM   log l
   WHERE  log_date <= :mydate
   ORDER  BY user_id, log_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT l                            -- whole row
           FROM   log l
           WHERE  l.user_id > (c.my_row).user_id
           AND    l.log_date <= :mydate        -- repeat condition
           ORDER  BY l.user_id, l.log_date DESC NULLS LAST
           LIMIT  1)
   FROM   cte c
   WHERE  (c.my_row).user_id IS NOT NULL       -- note parentheses
   )
SELECT (my_row).*                              -- decompose row
FROM   cte
WHERE  (my_row).user_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY (my_row).user_id;
```

Convenient to retrieve a *single column* or the *whole row*. The example uses the whole row type of the table. Other variants are possible.

To assert a row was found in the previous iteration, test a single NOT NULL column (like the primary key).

*More explanation for this query in chapter 2b. below.*

Related:

- [Query last N related rows per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957558/querying-last-n-related-records-in-postgres/25965393#25965393)
- [GROUP BY one column, while sorting by another in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74811/3684)

### 2. With separate `users` table

Table layout hardly matters as long as exactly one row per relevant `user_id` is guaranteed. Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
 , username text NOT NULL
);
```

Ideally, the table is physically sorted in sync with the `log` table. See:

- [Optimize Postgres query on timestamp range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998139/optimize-postgres-timestamp-query-range/14007963#14007963)

Or it's small enough (low cardinality) that it hardly matters. Else, sorting rows in the query can help to further optimize performance. [See Gang Liang's addition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36223670/939860)  If the physical sort order of the `users` table happens to match the index on `log`, this may be irrelevant.

#### 2a. `LATERAL` join

```sql
SELECT u.user_id, l.log_date, l.payload
FROM   users u
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT l.log_date, l.payload
   FROM   log l
   WHERE  l.user_id = u.user_id         -- lateral reference
   AND    l.log_date <= :mydate
   ORDER  BY l.log_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) l;
```

[`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) allows to reference preceding `FROM` items on the same query level. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Results in one index (-only) look-up per user.

Returns no row for users missing in the `users` table. Typically, a **foreign key** constraint enforcing referential integrity would rule that out.

Also, no row for users without matching entry in `log` - conforming to the original question. To keep those users in the result use **`LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`** instead of `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

Use **`LIMIT n`** instead of `LIMIT 1` to retrieve **more than one rows** (but not all) per user.

Effectively, all of these do the same:

```
JOIN LATERAL ... ON true
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ...
, LATERAL ...
```

The last one has lower priority, though. Explicit `JOIN` binds before comma. That subtle difference can matters with more join tables. See:

- ["invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table" in Postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597700/invalid-reference-to-from-clause-entry-for-table-in-postgres-query/34598292#34598292)

#### 2b. Correlated subquery

Good choice to retrieve a **single column** from a **single row**. Code example:

- [Optimize groupwise maximum query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244026/optimize-groupwise-maximum-query/24377356#24377356)

The same is possible for **multiple columns**, but you need more smarts:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE combo (log_date date, payload int);

SELECT user_id, (combo1).*              -- note parentheses
FROM (
   SELECT u.user_id
        , (SELECT (l.log_date, l.payload)::combo
           FROM   log l
           WHERE  l.user_id = u.user_id
           AND    l.log_date <= :mydate
           ORDER  BY l.log_date DESC NULLS LAST
           LIMIT  1) AS combo1
   FROM   users u
   ) sub;
```

Like `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` above, this variant includes *all* users, even without entries in `log`. You get `NULL` for `combo1`, which you can easily filter with a `WHERE` clause in the outer query if need be.
<sub>Nitpick: in the outer query you can't distinguish whether the subquery didn't find a row or all column values happen to be NULL - same result. You need a `NOT NULL` column in the subquery to avoid this ambiguity.</sub>

A correlated subquery can only return a **single value**. You can wrap multiple columns into a composite type. But to decompose it later, Postgres demands a well-known composite type. Anonymous records can only be decomposed providing a column definition list.
Use a registered type like the row type of an existing table. Or register a composite type explicitly (and permanently) with `CREATE TYPE`. Or create a temporary table (dropped automatically at end of session) to register its row type temporarily. Cast syntax: `(log_date, payload)::combo`

Finally, we do not want to decompose `combo1` on the same query level. Due to a weakness in the query planner this would evaluate the subquery once for each column (still true in Postgres 12). Instead, make it a subquery and decompose in the outer query.

Related:

- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group/25173081#25173081)

Demonstrating all 4 queries with 100k log entries and 1k users:
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=de6abcb0f57d39553f8b58791b9f8518)* - pg 11
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fad8f/7)</sub>

Comment: I swear: Erwin Brandstetter is the lead developer at PostgreSQL. Such an impressive wealth of knowledge on the subject.

Comment: Made my day. The "Recursive CTE with LATERAL join" is fantastic. Would never have thought of doing it that way.

Comment: @Erwin Let's assume the log table contains an enum column logType -> SYSTEM_LOG, APPLICATION_LOG, DATABASE_LOG. Can you tell me how to obtain the three latest logTypes for each user in this case using 1a?

Answer (score 14):

This is not a standalone answer but rather a comment to @Erwin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/2684232). For 2a, the lateral join example, the query can be improved by sorting the `users` table to exploit the locality of the index on `log`.

```
SELECT u.user_id, l.log_date, l.payload
  FROM (SELECT user_id FROM users ORDER BY user_id) u,
       LATERAL (SELECT log_date, payload
                  FROM log
                 WHERE user_id = u.user_id -- lateral reference
                   AND log_date <= :mydate
              ORDER BY log_date DESC NULLS LAST
                 LIMIT 1) l;
```

The rationale is that index lookup is expensive if `user_id` values are random. By sorting out `user_id` first, the subsequent lateral join would be like a simple scan on the index of `log`. Even though both query plans look alike, the running time would differ much especially for large tables.

The cost of the sorting is minimal especially if there is an index on the `user_id` field.

Comment: This can be a valid improvement if the use case fits. I added a pointer to this addition in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a different index on the table would help.  Try this one:  `log(user_id, log_date)`.  I am not positive that Postgres will make optimal use with `distinct on`.

So, I would stick with that index and try this version:

```
select *
from log l
where not exists (select 1
                  from log l2
                  where l2.user_id = l.user_id and
                        l2.log_date <= :mydate and
                        l2.log_date > l.log_date
                 );
```

This should replace the sorting/grouping with index look ups.  It might be faster.